# How can I use a variable inside a ng-repeat expression?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code

```
  <tbody ng:repeat="i in data">
    <tr>
        <td>{{i.Dia}}</td><td>{{i.TMed}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Is it possible to use a variable instead of "TMed" like "api_method"?

```
        <td>{{i.Dia}}</td><td>{{i.api_method}}</td>
```

Thank you very much

Hugo

Comment: What is your question? What is `TMed`?

Comment: Is `api_method` defined on `i`?

Comment: By `api_method`, do you mean a function call? Can you write a plunker for the essence of your question?

Comment: Thank you. TMed is a key of the object. TMed is a variable. Depending on the request, the object comes with diferent keys. I would like to use a variable to express it.

Comment: may be use like `i[i.api_method]`?

Comment: i[i.api_method] not working...

Comment: may be you need to provide more codes and post part of json data from your api. we dont know what your data looks like.

Comment: [
  {
    "Dia": "2011-11-01",
    "TMed": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Dia": "2011-11-02",
    "TMed": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Dia": "2011-11-03",
    "TMed": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Dia": "2011-11-04",
    "TMed": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Dia": "2011-11-05",
    "TMed": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Dia": "2011-11-06",
    "TMed": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Dia": "2011-11-07",
    "TMed": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Dia": "2011-11-08",
    "TMed": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Dia": "2011-11-09",
    "TMed": "0.0"
  },
  {
    "Dia": "2011-11-10",
    "TMed": "0.0"
  }
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your problem:
http://plnkr.co/edit/k9hz9o5BfHGNWe9wMJCq?p=preview

If you access the key of a JavaScript object with array syntax, you can use variables:

```
<td>{{ i[api_method] }}</td>
```

You can define `data` and `api_method` anywhere, for example in `MainCtrl`:

```
  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.api_method = 'TMed';
    $scope.data = [ 
      { "Dia": "2011-11-01", "TMed": "0.0" }
      // more data...
    ];
  });
```